# Dynamic content in fancybox 2

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I am facing issue getting html of the sibling of a clicked element into the content and showing in a fancybox.

My html is

```
<a href="#" class="no-republish">Republish</a>
<p class="no-republish-message">Please try again after few days.</p>
```

My js is

```
$(".no-republish").click(function(e) {
    $.fancybox({
        type: 'inline',
        beforeShow: function () {
            this.href = $(this.element).next('.no-republish-message').html();
        },
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: What actualy tou want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing js to the following works perfectly

```
$(".no-republish").click(function(e) {
    var c = $(this).next('.no-republish-message').html();
    $.fancybox({
        content: c,
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```